# MATLAB Thresholding

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am using the following MATLAB code for Niblack Binarization.

```
    mean= averagefilter2(image1);
    meanSquare = averagefilter2(image1.^2);
    standardDeviation = (meanSquare - mean.^2).^0.5;
    binaryImage = image1 >=  (mean + k_threshold * standardDeviation);

   function img=averagefilter2(image1)
       meanFilter = fspecial('average',[60 60]);
       img = imfilter (image1,meanFilter);
   end
```

But when I implement it, 
[image: Original Image] 
becomes
 [image: Binarised Image].

(Ignore the black border..it is just to highlight the white patch on the edge of the image)

That is, near the edges some data pixels go missing and becomes white (the white patch at the top and right edges). Am I wrong anywhere in this implementation? Is there a better "MATLAB way" of implementing it, or should I do it manually using nested loops for calculating average and standard deviation?

Comment: I suggest you add a [mcve], meaning full code to replicate your results

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I've updated it now.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? I bet that white are is about 30 pixels wide (half your 2nd filter)

Comment: Yes.
Thanks a lot. It's working perfectly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely this is due to boundary conditions of the `imfilter` function, and perharps from your own function `averagefilter2`.

When you filter, in the edge cases, you need to access pixels that are outside the image. That means that you need to make assumptions on what happens outside the boundary.

`imfilter` has [a parameter](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html#inputarg_options) to choose what is assumed to be outside, and it is assumed to be zero by default. That would definetly cause a smaller value for the mean and perhaps that makes the binarization get "deleted" there.

Try different values, and surely implement that for your own function also.

I suggest starting with `'symmetric'`